# puppeteer@5.5.0 install: `node install.js` on M1

Tags: node.js, macos, puppeteer, apple-m1

I've been trying to work on a code I wrote a couple of months back ran into the following error,

```
> puppeteer@5.5.0 install /Users/xyz/Documents/xyz.github.io/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

The chromium binary is not available for arm64: 
If you are on Ubuntu, you can install with: 

 apt-get install chromium-browser

/Users/xyz/Documents/xyz.github.io/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js:112
            throw new Error();

Error
    at /Users/xyz/Documents/xyz.github.io/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js:112:19
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
```

Chromium arm64 is installed for some reason puppeteer doesn't seem to recognize it. Any workaround for the above?

Solutions I've tried :

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6622

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Fixed via [50b810d](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/commit/9a8479a52a7d8b51690b0732b2a10816cd1b8aef). Clean install node modules

Type the following in the terminal `sudo nano ~/.zshrc` , copy the code below & paste proceed to save.

```
export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true
export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=`which chromium`
```

1. Remove existing node modules, package-lock.json & cache from the project.

   `rm -rf node_modules/`
   `rm -rf package-lock.json`
   `rm -rf .cache`
2. Install node modules.

   `npm i`

Patch works.

----- Updated ------------- (27/04/2021)

Make sure you've to install chromium. If you haven't follow @Rocco's advice `brew install --cask chromium`.

----- Updated ------------- (18/11/2021)

[Hajonsoft](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6622#issuecomment-968183786) updated the thread on github -  https://www.courier.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-to-setup-your-apple-m1-for-development while this maybe a good fix for most developers & dependencies/tools please note that [rosetta emulation is not available in certain regions](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Evg3-qUXYAMdDdp?format=jpg&name=4096x4096) verified it myself in southeast asia.

------------ Updated ------------------ (04/06/2022)

In case in which chromium is not installed properly please follow @Tomer Omri
advice and run `brew install chromium --no-quarantine`.

------------ Updated ------------------ (26/12/2023)

Issue still persists with M2 & M3 systems the above solution has been tested and works fine. No issues observed to date.

Comment: Make sure you install chromium before all that via `brew install --cask chromium` and also to  open a new terminal after changes in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Rocco I will update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the answer above, I needed to run:

```
brew install chromium --no-quarantine
```

On my M1 so the chromium will be installed correctly

Comment: Thanks Tomer Omri for the input haven't updated this thread for a while. All please follow this additional step to ensure a seamless installation.