# The chromium binary is not available for arm64

Tags: macos, apple-m1, macos-monterey

I am using [rush](https://github.com/microsoft/rushstack) and trying to run `rush install` in a project I cloned from one of my company's repositories. But, it fails by throwing the following error:

```
The chromium binary is not available for arm64: 
  If you are on Ubuntu, you can install with:
  apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Note: I'm using iTerm2 terminal for all this running on an Apple Macbook Pro having **Monterey** as the OS, powered by the **Apple M1 Pro** chip.

PS I tried to look for answers o'er the web and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65928783/puppeteer5-5-0-install-node-install-js-on-m1) post but the answer doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: The answer `brew install chromium --no-quarantine` was working for me.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned previously, this is due to the new M1 chips. I've been able to resolve the issue by using node v15. Could try `nvm use 15` from the command line in your project directory.

Comment: rather no, I found this error on docker image 'FROM node:16' as well ;FROM node:19'